# tkinter text entry text deletes itself upon pressing a button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So, I am having trouble with the Entry box in tkinter. Whenever I press the "Submit" button, the string inside the text entry boxes deletes. And I very well believe that this is the source of my problems with the output.

The following code shows the entry boxes that are defined and used (the formatting may be a little off from the actual code):

```
def var_use():   
    Label (window, text="Metric or Imperial Unit?:", bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=9, column=10, sticky=W)
    textbox_measurement = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white", fg="black") 
    textbox_measurement.grid(row=10, column=10, sticky=W)
    Label (window, text="Please enter your weight here:", bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=11, column=10, sticky=W)
    textbox_weight = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white", fg="black") 
    textbox_weight.grid(row=12, column=10, sticky=W)
    Label (window, text="Please as well, enter your height:", bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=13, column=10, sticky=W)
    textbox_height = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white", fg="black") 
    textbox_height.grid(row=14, column=10, sticky=W)
    return textbox_measurement
    return textbox_weight
    return textbox_height     #so i can call variables from this function
    var_use()
```

The next lines I have just show a part of the submit button:

```
def click_submit():  
    BMI_Calc()
    BMI_output = BMI_Calc()
    output.delete(0.0, END)
    output.insert(END, str(BMI_output))
```

BMI_Calc I have tested and I know that it works. I need to get the BMI_output, but I can't, I'm pretty sure that it's because the text inside the text entry boxes is being deleted.

Comment: You need to fix the indentation in your examples.

Comment: We can't be sure until you show us a [mcve], but I'll bet that you are not deleting the contents, you are probably creating a new Entry widget and placing it on top of the old one, covering it up.

Comment: @Novel Thanks, it's fixed, you were right, the function was repeated multiple times, therefore covering it up